# Showing that $B=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2} \mid \ xy>0 \}$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $$B=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2} \mid \ xy>0 \}$$ is an open set in the Euclidean space $(\Bbb{R^2},d_2),$ where $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$.

Defining $A= \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2} \mid x>0,y>0 \}$ and $E=\{  (x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2} \mid x<0,y<0 \}$ one sees that $B= A\cup E$ and thus $B$ will be open if $A$ and $E$ are open.

How can I show that $A$ and $E$ are both open? It seems that I would need to find open balls with arbitrary radius $B((x,y), r)$ for both cases that are contained in the set I'm working with?

Comment: Draw a picture. Pick a point in $B$, say it is in the region $A$ as you defined. Then $x>0$ and $y>0$. Can you see what is the radius of ball you can pick about $(x,y)$ so that you guarantee points in that ball will still have the property that both coordinates are positive?

Comment: For $(x,y)=(5,8)$, $r=5$ works. For $(x,y) = (10,3)$, $r=3$ works. Can you generalize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show $B^C$ is closed.

In fact $B^C = \{x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2,xy\leqslant 0\}$.

If you take $(x_n,y_n)$ a sequence of elements of $B^C$ that converges to $(x,y)$, then for all $n$, $x_ny_n \leqslant 0$.

When $n\rightarrow +\infty$, you get $xy \leqslant 0$.

So $(x,y)\in B^C$.

So $B^C$ is closed.

So $B$ is an open set.

Answer (score 2):

For $(x,y) \in A$ notice that
$$(x,y) \in B\left((x,y),\frac12\min\{|x|,|y|\}\right) \subseteq A$$
and the same thing for $E$.

For example, if $(x',y') \in B\left((x,y),\frac12\min\{|x|,|y|\}\right)$ we have
$$x-x' \le |x-x'| \le \sqrt{|x-x'|^2 + |y-y'|^2} \le \|(x,y)-(x',y')\| < \frac{x}2 $$
so $x'> \frac{x}2>0$. You can show the other inequalities similarly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why you're considering $d(x,x')$ and not $d((x,y), (x',y'))$?

Comment: @DanielLi I was doing it to show $B\left((x,y),\frac12\min\{|x|,|y|\}\right) \subseteq A$ if $(x,y) \in A$.

Comment: It's confusing me a bit that you're considering only the $x$ coordinates of $(x,y)$ and $(x', y')$

Comment: @DanielLi Aha, I wrote that you can show other inequalities similarly, you should also show $$y-y' \le |y-y'| \le \sqrt{|x-x'|^2 + |y-y'|^2} \le \|(x,y)-(x',y')\| < \frac{y}2$$
which implies $y' > \frac{y}2 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$B = (-\infty,0)\times(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$$
Since each of these is an open set, so $B$ is an open set.

Comment: OP wants to know why both those sets are open.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication $f\colon
\begin{cases}\mathbb R^2&\to\mathbb R;\\
(x,y)&\mapsto x\cdot y
\end{cases}$ is known to be continuous.  Observe that $B$ is the preimage of the open set $(0,\infty)$ under $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x>0, y>0,$ and suppose $\min\{x,y\}=y.$ [A very similar proof can be done if $\min\{x,y\}=x$ ].

I want to do better than mechanodroid and show that $B\left(\ (x,y),\ y\ \right) \subseteq A$ which amounts to:

If $\ d\left(\ (x,y),\ (x',y')\ \right) < y,\ $ then $x' > 0$ and $y' > 0.$

Since showing that $x'>0\ $ is easier than showing $y' > 0,$ I'll concentrate on $y'$ and leave $x'$ as an exercise for the reader.

If $y' \geq y,$ then we are done since $y>0.$ So suppose further that $y' < y.$

By supposition, \begin{align} 0 < \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2} < y \\
\implies (x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 < y^2 \\
\implies 0 \leq (x-x')^2 < 2yy' - (y')^2 = y'(2y-y').
\end{align}

If $y'=0$ then $(x-x')^2 < 0 \ \Rightarrow\Leftarrow.$

If $y' < 0,$ then we require $2y - y' < 0$, which is true $\iff 0< 2y<y'<y\ \Rightarrow\Leftarrow.$

Therefore $y'>0.$